# Why does the ssh-agent have no identities after starting the agent and running ssh-add?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, macos-monterey, ssh-agent

I am trying to configure ssh for use with github on a new computer.  I've attempted to follow the instructions listed in the [tutorial on github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to no avail.  Here's a summary.

Using my M1 mac's (macOS 12.6) terminal console, I first check that I have created a public private key pair.  The command `ls -la ~/.ssh` produces

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 <user>  staff   192 Sep 16 21:26 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 34 <user>  staff  1088 Sep 17 07:12 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 <user>  staff    75 MMM DD HH:MM config
-rw-------   1 <user>  staff  2655 MMM DD HH:MM id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 <user>  staff   571 MMM DD HH:MM id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 <user>  staff    92 MMM DD HH:MM known_hosts
```

It appears I have a private key with owner read/write permissions.  I then check the contents of the private key file with `cat ~/id_rsa`.  The terminal prints

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY--—-
random looking stuff
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY--—-
```

Next I check the config file (just in case it's relevant) with `cat ~/.ssh/config` and I get

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now I start the ssh-agent with `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and I get `Agent pid XXX`.  Great.  I run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.  The terminal asks for my private key passphrase, which I enter, and it finishes silently.  Finally, to check that the operation was successful I run `'ssh-add -l`, and the result says

```
The agent has no identities.
```

For good measure, I try adding the public key to my github account and I try connecting to git with `ssh -vT git@github.com`.  I see a line saying

```
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It asks me for my passphrase, which I enter, and it says

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Anyone have any ideas about what might be going on?  Why isn't the `ssh-add` being successful?  Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue on macOS Monterey on a specific machine, but it works fine on a different machine with the same OS. murky-lion did you ever figure this one out?